# Why the ValidationMessage component does not show error message in Blazor wasm when using the EditContext

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I create a form with Blazor wasm and I use the EditContext attribute (not the Model attribute)

```
<EditForm EditContext="@FormEditContext"  OnSubmit="@HandleSubmitAsync">
```

The problem I have is with the **ValidationMessage** component in my razor page: it does not show the error message.
If I use the Model attribute instead of EditContext attribute, the ValidationMessage work well, it show the error message...

The code that handle the submit is:

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<bool> ValidationResult { get; set; }

public async Task HandleSubmitAsync()
{
   bool isValid = FormEditContext.Validate();
   await ValidationResult.InvokeAsync(isValid);
}
```

for now, nothing is done by the ValidationResult handler... so this is not a problem...

I create the EditContext like this:

```
private EditContext FormEditContext;
protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
   FormEditContext = new EditContext(MyModel);
   return base.OnInitializedAsync();
}
```

In the razor page I use the ValidationMessage component like this:

```
<ValidationMessage For=@(() => MyModel.FirstName)></ValidationMessage>
```

My model implement IValidatableObject and in the Validate function return validation lie this:

```
yield return new ValidationResult("FirstName required", new[] { "FirstName" });
```

For information, the ValidationSummary component show the error message..